# Special characters (ë) in JSON-response

Tags: php, ajax, json, special-characters

My database stores some texts which I have to get with AJAX. This is going well but only when it not contains special characters such as ë or ä. I found some articles about this topic which told me to change the charset of the AJAX-request, but none of these worked for me.

When I start firebug it said this about the headers:

**Antwoordheaders (dutch for responseheaders)**
Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection  close
Content-Length  94
Content-Type    text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15
Date    Wed, 26 Sep 2012 09:52:56 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache
X-Powered-By    PleskLin

**Verzoekheaders (dutch for requestheaders)**
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Authorization   Basic c3BvdGlkczp6SkBVajRrcw==
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15
Cookie  __utma=196329838.697518114.1346065716.1346065716.1346065716.1;   __utmz=196329838.1346065716.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none);   PHPSESSID=2h4vu8gu9v8fe5l1t3ad5agp86
DNT 1
Host    www.spotids.com
Referer http://www.spotids.com/private/?p=16
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1

Both of the headers are talking about charset=ISO-8859-15 which should include characters like ë, but it doesn't work for me.

The code I used for this (PHP):

```
`$newresult = mysql_query($query2);    
    $result = array();
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($newresult))
    {
        array_push($result, $row);
    }
    $jsonText = json_encode($result);
    echo $jsonText;`
```

Comment: By standards, you should deliver JSON data in UTF-8, most likely. ISO-8859-15 may contain the characters you need, but is that the format your JSON is in? Probably not, since it's being taken straight out of MySQL. It's anyone's guess how MySQL is storing and delivering the text to you, which is why it's best to just force everything to use UTF-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make sure you set the headers to UTF-8:

   ```
   header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
   ```
2. Make sure your connection to database is made with UTF-8 encoding before any queries:

   ```
   $query = mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
   ```
3. As far as I know, JSON encodes any characters that cannot be represented in pure ASCII. And you should decode that JSON on response.
4. Try to move to PDO as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use this nice [tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers#Getting_Row_Count)

Answer (score 1):

From JSON RFC-4627 : `JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
   UTF-8.`
Use `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv` to change string encoding.

And send correct header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

verify the Content-Type meat

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```