# json.Parse on special character and becomes null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Error:

`data[i].last_name is null`

I check the result from php and which has "Beñas" which triggers the null value.

```
 xhr.queue({
    url: 'controller/agents_handler.php',
    data: {load_request: 'top_earners'},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        var topEarnersDiv = $('.top_earners_container ul');
        var str = "";
        for ( i in data) {
             str += '<p class="lastname boldthis">'+data[i].last_name.substr(0,8)+'</p>';
        }
   topEarnersDiv.html(str);
   }
```

Sample response:

```
 {
  "user_id": "12345",
  "user_name": "johnb",
  "first_name": "john",
  "last_name": null
  }
```

from php response:

it has `Beñas` value which becomes `null`

PHP:

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE x= active";
  db::query($sql);
  $mtd_list = array();
  while ($rows = db::fetch_assoc()) :
       $mtd_list[] = $rows;
   endwhile;

  return $mtd_list;
```

Comment: Please post an example of the response. I find it already suspicious that you are calling `var data = JSON.parse(data)`, even though jQuery already decoded the response for you (`dataType:"json"`). If that works, it means that you encoded your data as JSON at least *twice*. What exactly is the value of `data`?

Comment: hi. added a sample response of the json object, also `dataType: "json"` is just a test fixed that didn't work out. I deleted it.

Comment: OK, so the value is already `null` when it comes to the client. The problem is on the server side then. We can't help you if you don't post how you generate the data.

Comment: check here also about the headers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599258/special-characters-%C3%AB-in-json-response

Comment: When echoing the response prepend `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: @Felix that's true -- OP whats happening over at the PHP script? how are you forming the data

Comment: added the simple php function that returns the data.

Answer (score 0):

It should be an enconding error, if you change change the php code, you should use `utf8_encode()` to parse every string in that object.

Comment: Why should the OP try this? `utf8_encode` expects a **string** as input. Do you assume that `$yourStuff` is a string? It also returns a string. What's the point of calling `json_encode` on a string?